# Django deploy angular

Tags: python, django, apache, angularjs

Okey, so i have build a working angular app and I am now trying to deploy it using django (1.6). I have 2 questions,firstly why does django serve the static files, so veeery slow? (takes  up to 1 minute to load the site compared to 2-5 sec using just apache2) Secound how do i serve the views i have build with angular?  (bunos question, really confused with all the static files, could someone please explain the where and how i should store all static files?)

This is the file layout:

```
 var/wwww/
    PhotodiceServer (generated from the "startproject" command)/
        apache/
            django.wsgi
        media/
        photod (generated from the "startapp" command)/
            static/
                css/
                    ...
                js/
                    ...
                scripts/
                    ...
                templates/
                    ...
                views/
                    feed.html
                    ...
            template/
                index.html
            admin.py
            urls.py
            models.py
            ...
        PotodiceServer/
            static/
            setting.py
            urls.py
            ...
        static/
            admin/
                 css
                 ...
```

This is the index file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="photodice">
<head>
 {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/bootstrapCustomized.css" %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/PhotodiceMain.css"  %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/newProject.css"  %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/photodiceanimation.css"  %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/myPages.css"  %}>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/fb.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/edit.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/FileSaver.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/jszip.min.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/pixastic.core.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/invert.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/sepia.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/desaturate.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/fliph.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/lighten.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/blurfast.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/sharpen.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/crop.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/coloradjust.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/brightness.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/pixastic/actions/hsl.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/angular/AngularV.1.3.0/angular.min.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js" %}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/angular/angular-animate.min.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "scripts/photodice.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "scripts/angularLocalStorage.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "scripts/mainNavCtrl.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "js/jQuery.js" %}></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>PhotoDice</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <div id="navbarcontainer">
        <div class="viewDiv" ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentcontainer">
        <div class="viewDiv" ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fottercontainer">
    </div>
    <!--scrips-->
</body>
</html>
```

This what i have added to the apache config file in /etcc/apache2:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/PhotodiceServer

AddHandler wsgi-script .py

<Directory /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer>
Options +ExecCGI
SetHandler wsgi-script
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

(bonus question) would the result be the same if I put the above code in availale sites folder as a virtural server? what would i have to chang add?

this is the urls.py file (located in photod):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url('^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

from the settings file:

```
import os.path
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),     'static'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/PhotodiceServer/media/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense at all. Django is not a thing you "deploy" a static Javascript app with. If you were building a dynamic data-driven app using Django as the backend and Angular as the front end, that would be a different thing, but you don't appear to be doing so here.

Apart from anything else, Django is specifically **not** meant for serving static assets such as Javascript files. There are warnings all over the documentation warning against doing this. Even in a normal Django site, you must serve your JS files directly via the web server. Of course, doing so on your site would make Django completely irrelevant.

Comment: Okey, (so i obiously know way to little about django...) I am doing this as part of a course and i am required to have a large scale backend, althoug i really just want to use it for some really easy interactions with the database... how would i go about that?